# validate textfield contents in wordpress simple job board plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, validation

how to validate text field content in job application form ?? to make sure the content holding only characters from A-Z and a-z, to avoid SQL injection and other bad string such as *|_"'*$@!;...etc  ???

Comment: actually, after spend a lot of time of searching, i didn't found answer.

Answer (score 1):

Any good plugin should already have text sanitization. If you want to sanitize the text yourself via custom php code, you may use built-in PHP of WordPress functions for this job:

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

or

https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

For example for a text-field input we can filter contents like this:

```
$title = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['title'] );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title', $title );
```

Answer (score 0):

i customize the sjb(simple job board) plugin via add content validation with specific pattern for any text field that generate by plugin in application form, which allow only characters [A-Z, a-z].

just replace this file
simple-job-board/templates/single-jobpost/job-application.php
by this code:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Display the job application form.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/simple_job_board/single-jobpost/job-application.php
 *
 * @author  PressTigers
 * @package     Simple_Job_Board
 * @subpackage  Simple_Job_Board/Templates
 * @version     1.0.0
 * @since       2.1.0
 * @since       2.2.2   Added more @hooks in application form.
 * @since       2.3.0   Added "sjb_job_application_template" filter & "sjb_job_application_form_fields" filter.
 */
ob_start();
global $post;

/**
 * Fires on job detail page before displaying job application section.
 *                  
 * @since   2.1.0                   
 */
do_action('sjb_job_application_before');
?>

<!-- Start Job Application Form
================================================== -->
<form class="jobpost-form" id="sjb-application-form" name="c-assignments-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3><?php echo apply_filters('sjb_job_application_form_title', esc_html__('Apply Online', 'simple-job-board')); ?></h3>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
            /**
             * Fires on job detail page at start of job application form. 
             *                 
             * @since   2.3.0                   
             */
            do_action('sjb_job_application_form_fields_start');

            $keys = get_post_custom_keys(get_the_ID());
            if (NULL != $keys):
                foreach ($keys as $key):
                    if (substr($key, 0, 7) == 'jobapp_'):
                        $val = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), $key, TRUE);
                        $val = unserialize($val);
                        $is_required = isset($val['optional']) ? "checked" === $val['optional'] ? 'required="required"' : "" : 'required="required"';
                        $required_class = isset($val['optional']) ? "checked" === $val['optional'] ? "sjb-required" : "sjb-not-required" : "sjb-required";
                        $required_field_asterisk = isset($val['optional']) ? "checked" === $val['optional'] ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : "" : '<span id="sjb-required">*</span>';
                        $id = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\_]/u', '_', $key);
                        $name = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\_]/u', '_', $key);
                        $label = isset($val['label']) ? $val['label'] : ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($key, 7)));

                        // Field Type Meta
                        $field_type_meta = array(
                            'id' => $id,
                            'name' => $name,
                            'label' => $label,
                            'type' => $val['type'],
                            'is_required' => $is_required,
                            'required_class' => $required_class,
                            'required_field_asterisk' => $required_field_asterisk,
                        );

                        /**
                         * Fires on job detail page at start of job application form. 
                         *                 
                         * @since   2.3.0                   
                         */
                        do_action('sjb_job_application_form_fields', $field_type_meta);
        //. '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" class="form-control ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . ' >'

                        switch ($val['type']) {
                            case 'text':
                                echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                . '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" class="form-control sjb-text ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '><span class="sjb-invalid-text validity-note">' . esc_html__('A valid  text is required.', 'simple-job-board') . '</span>'
                                . '</div>';
                                break;
                            case 'text_area':
                                echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                . '<textarea name="' . $name . '" class="form-control ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '></textarea>'
                                . '</div>';
                                break;
                            case 'email':
                                echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                . '<input type="email" name="' . $name . '" class="form-control sjb-email-address ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '><span class="sjb-invalid-email validity-note">' . esc_html__('A valid email address is required.', 'simple-job-board') . '</span>'
                                . '</div>';
                                break;
                            case 'phone':
                                echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                . '<input type="tel" name="' . $name . '" class="form-control sjb-phone-number ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '><span class="sjb-invalid-phone validity-note" id="' . $id . '-invalid-phone">' . esc_html__('A valid phone number is required.', 'simple-job-board') . ' </span>'
                                . '</div>';
                                break;
                            case 'date':
                                echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                . '<input type="text" name="' . $name . '" class="form-control sjb-datepicker ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '>'
                                . '</div>';
                                break;
                            case 'radio':
                                if ($val['options'] != '') {
                                    echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                    . '<label class="sjb-label-control" for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                    . '<div id="' . $key . '" >';
                                    $options = explode(',', $val['options']);
                                    $i = 0;
                                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                                        echo '<label class="small"><input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" class=" ' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" value="' . $option . '"  ' . sjb_is_checked( $i ) . ' ' . $is_required . '>' . $option . ' </label> ';
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                    echo '</div></div>';
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'dropdown':
                                if ($val['options'] != '') {
                                    echo '<div class="form-group">'
                                    . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                    . '<div id="' . $key . '" >'
                                    . '<select class="form-control" name="' . $name . '" id="' . $id . '" ' . $is_required . '>';
                                    $options = explode(',', $val['options']);
                                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                                        echo '<option class="' . $required_class . '" value="' . $option . '" >' . $option . ' </option>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</select></div></div>';
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'checkbox' :
                                if ($val['options'] != '') {
                                    echo '<div class="form-group ">'
                                    . '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $label . $required_field_asterisk . '</label>'
                                    . '<div id="' . $key . '">';
                                    $options = explode(',', $val['options']);
                                    $i = 0;

                                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                                        echo '<label class="small"><input type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '[]" class="' . $required_class . '" id="' . $id . '" value="' . $option . '"  ' . $i . ' ' . $is_required . '>' . $option . ' </label>';
                                        $i++;
                                    }
                                    echo '</div></div>';
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    endif;
                endforeach;
            endif;

            /**
             * Modify the output of file upload button. 
             * 
             * @since   2.2.0 
             * 
             * @param   string  $sjb_attach_resume  Attach resume button.
             */
            $sjb_attach_resume = '<div class="form-group">'
                    . '<label for="applicant_resume">' . apply_filters('sjb_resume_label', __('Attach Resume', 'simple-job-board')) . '<span class="sjb-required required">*</span></label>'
                    . '<input type="file" name="applicant_resume" id="applicant-resume" class="sjb-attachment form-control "' . apply_filters('sjb_resume_required', 'required="required"') . '>'
                    . '<span class="sjb-invalid-attachment validity-note" id="file-error-message"></span>'
                    . '</div>';
            echo apply_filters('sjb_attach_resume', $sjb_attach_resume);

            /**
             * Fires on job detail page before job submit button. 
             *                 
             * @since   2.2.0                   
             */
            do_action('sjb_job_application_form_fields_end');
            ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_applicant_form" >
            <input type="hidden" name="wp_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('jobpost_security_nonce') ?>" >
            <div class="form-group" id="sjb-form-padding-button">
                <button class="btn btn-primary app-submit"><?php esc_html_e('Submit', 'simple-job-board'); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
/**
 * Fires on job detail page after displaying job application form.
 *                  
 * @since 2.1.0                   
 */
do_action('sjb_job_application_end');
?>

<div id="jobpost_form_status"></div>
<!-- ==================================================
End Job Application Form -->

<?php
/**
 * Fires on job detail page after displaying job application section.
 *                  
 * @since   2.1.0                   
 */
do_action('sjb_job_application_after');

$html_job_application = ob_get_clean();

/**
 * Modify the Job Applicatin Form Template. 
 *                                       
 * @since   2.3.0
 * 
 * @param   html    $html_job_application   Job Application Form HTML.                   
 */
echo apply_filters('sjb_job_application_template', $html_job_application);
```

and this file simple-job-board/public/js/simple-job-board-public.js
with this code

```html
/**
  * Simple Job Board Core Front-end JS File - V 1.4.0
  * 
  * @author PressTigers <support@presstigers.com>, 2016
  *
  * Actions List
  * - Job Application Submission Callbacks
  * - Date Picker Initialization
  * - Validate Email 
  * - Initialize TelInput Plugin
  * - Validate Phone Number
  * - Allowable Uploaded File's Extensions
  * - Validate Required Inputs ( Attachment, Phone & Email )
  * - Checkbox Group Required Attribute Callbacks
  * - Custom Styling of File Upload Button 
  */
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jobpost_submit_button = $('.app-submit');
        
        $(".jobpost-form").on("submit", function (event) {
            var jobpost_form_status = $('#jobpost_form_status');
            var datastring = new FormData(document.getElementById("sjb-application-form"));

            /** 
             * Application Form Submit -> Validate Email & Phone & text
             * @since 2.2.0          
             */
            var is_valid_email = sjb_is_valid_input(event, "email", "sjb-email-address");
            var is_valid_phone = sjb_is_valid_input(event, "phone", "sjb-phone-number");
  var is_valid_text = sjb_is_valid_input(event, "text", "sjb-text");
            var is_attachment = sjb_is_attachment(event);

            /* Stop Form Submission on Invalid Phone, Email & File Attachement Plus text*/
            if ( !is_valid_email || !is_valid_phone || !is_attachment || !is_valid_text) {
                return false;
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: application_form.ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: datastring,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    jobpost_form_status.html('Submitting.....');
                    jobpost_submit_button.attr('disabled', 'diabled');
                },
                success: function ( response ) {
                    if ( response['success'] == true ) {
                        $('.jobpost-form').slideUp();

                        /* Translation Ready String Through Script Locaization */
                        jobpost_form_status.html(response['success_alert']);
                    }

                    if ( response['success'] == false ) {

                        /* Translation Ready String Through Script Locaization */
                        jobpost_form_status.html( response['error'] + ' ' + application_form.jquery_alerts['application_not_submitted'] + '</div>' );
                        jobpost_submit_button.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
                    }

                }
            });
            
            return false;
        });

        /* Date Picker */
        $('.sjb-datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

        /** 
         * Application Form -> On Input Email Validation
         *  
         * @since   2.2.0          
         */
        $('.sjb-email-address').on('input', function () {
            var input = $(this);
      //alert("emaiiiil");
            var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
            var is_email = re.test(input.val());
            var error_element = $("span", $(this).parent());
            if (is_email) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                error_element.hide();
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });
      
   /** 
         * Application Form -> On Input text Validation
         *  
         * @since   2.2.0          
         */
        $('.sjb-text').on('input', function () {
            var input = $(this);
            // var re = /^[a-zA-Z.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)*$/;
      var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
            var is_text = re.test(input.val());
            var error_element = $("span", $(this).parent());
      //error_element.show();
            if (is_text) {
                input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                error_element.hide();
            } else {
                input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
            }
        });
        /**
         * Initialize TelInput Plugin
         * 
         * @since   2.2.0
         */
        if ($('.sjb-phone-number').length) {
            var telInput_id = $('.sjb-phone-number').map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }).get();

            for (var input_ID in telInput_id) {
                var telInput = $('#' + telInput_id[input_ID]);
                telInput.intlTelInput({
                    initialCountry: "auto",
                    geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
                        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function () {
                        }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
                            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                            callback(countryCode);
                        });
                    },
                });
            }
        }

        /**
         * Application Form -> Phone Number Validation
         * 
         * @since 2.2.0
         */
        $('.sjb-phone-number').on('input', function () {
            var telInput = $(this);
            var telInput_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var error_element = $("#" + telInput_id + "-invalid-phone");
            error_element.hide();
            
            // Validate Phone Number
            if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
                if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
                    telInput.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                    error_element.hide();
                } else {
                    telInput.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                }
            }
        });

        /** 
         * Check for Allowable Extensions of Uploaded File
         *  
         * @since   2.3.0          
         */
        $('.sjb-attachment').on('change', function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var file = $("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
            var error_element = file.parent().next("span");
            error_element.text('');
            error_element.hide();

            // Validate on File Attachment
            if ( 0 != file.get(0).files.length ) {
                /**
                 *  Uploded File Extensions Checks
                 *  Get Uploded File Ext
                 */
                var file_ext = file.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

                // All Allowed File Extensions
                var allowed_file_exts = application_form.allowed_extensions;

                // Settings File Extensions && Getting value From Script Localization
                var settings_file_exts = application_form.setting_extensions;
                var selected_file_exts = (('yes' === application_form.all_extensions_check) || null == settings_file_exts) ? allowed_file_exts : settings_file_exts;

                // File Extension Validation
                if ($.inArray(file_ext, selected_file_exts) > -1) {
                    jobpost_submit_button.attr( 'disabled', false );
                    input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                } else {

                    /* Translation Ready String Through Script Locaization */
                    error_element.text(application_form.jquery_alerts['invalid_extension']);
                    error_element.show();
                    input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                }
            }
        });

        /** 
         * Stop Form Submission -> On Required Attachments
         *  
         * @since 2.3.0          
         */
        function sjb_is_attachment( event ) {
            var error_free = true;
            $(".sjb-attachment").each(function () {

                var element = $("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
                var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
                var is_required_class = element.hasClass("sjb-not-required");               

                // Set Error Indicator on Invalid Attachment
                if (!valid) {
                    if (!(is_required_class && 0 === element.get(0).files.length)) {
                        error_free = false;
                    }
                }

                // Stop Form Submission
                if (!error_free) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            return error_free;
        }

        /** 
         * Stop Form Submission -> On Invalid Email/Phone/text
         *  
         * @since 2.2.0          
         */
        function sjb_is_valid_input(event, input_type, input_class) {
            var jobpost_form_inputs = $("." + input_class).serializeArray();
            var error_free = true;
            for (var i in jobpost_form_inputs) {
                var element = $("#" + jobpost_form_inputs[i]['name']);
                var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
                var is_required_class = element.hasClass("sjb-not-required");
                if (!(is_required_class && "" === jobpost_form_inputs[i]['value'])) {
                    if ("email" === input_type) {
                        var error_element = $("span", element.parent());
                    } else if ("phone" === input_type) {
                        var error_element = $("#" + jobpost_form_inputs[i]['name'] + "-invalid-phone");
                    }else if ("text" === input_type) {
                        var error_element = $("span", element.parent());
                    }

                    // Set Error Indicator on Invalid Input
                    if (!valid) {
                        error_element.show();
                        error_free = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        error_element.hide();
                    }

                    // Stop Form Submission
                    if (!error_free) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
            return error_free;
        }
        
        /**
         * Remove Required Attribute from Checkbox Group -> When one of the option is selected.
         * Add Required Attribute from Checkboxes Group -> When none of the option is selected.
         * 
         * @since   2.3.0
         */
        var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
        requiredCheckboxes.on('change', function () {
            var checkboxGroup = requiredCheckboxes.filter('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]');
            var isChecked = checkboxGroup.is(':checked');
            checkboxGroup.prop('required', !isChecked);
        });

    });

    /* 
     * Custom Styling of Upload Field Button
     * 
     * @since   2.4.0
     */
    var file = {
        maxlength: 20, // maximum length of filename before it's trimmed
        
        convert: function () {
            // Convert all file type inputs.
            $('input[type=file].sjb-attachment').each(function () {
                $(this).wrap('<div class="file" />');
                $(this).parent().prepend('<div>'+ application_form.file['browse']+'</div>');
                $(this).parent().prepend('<span>'+ application_form.file['no_file_chosen']+'</span>');
                $(this).fadeTo(0, 0);
                $(this).attr('size', '50'); // Use this to adjust width for FireFox.
            });
        },
        update: function (x) {
            
            // Update the filename display.
            var filename = x.val().replace(/^.*\\/g, '');
            if (filename.length > $(this).maxlength) {
                trim_start = $(this).maxlength / 2 - 1;
                trim_end = trim_start + filename.length - $(this).maxlength + 1;
                filename = filename.substr(0, trim_start) + '&#8230;' + filename.substr(trim_end);
            }
            if (filename == '')
                filename = application_form.file['no_file_chosen'];
            x.siblings('span').html(filename);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        file.convert();
        $('input[type=file].sjb-attachment').change(function () {
            file.update($(this));
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note: my plugin Version is 2.4.6